# Having trouble getting nested ojects from json array in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, arraylist

Hello I have a jsonLines files **where I am trying to get all the Hashtags** (and Mentions which should be same process) from the jsonline file here: https://github.com/THsTestingGround/JsonL_Quest_SO/blob/master/output-2020-01-21.jsonl
(SO not allowing me to put urls, and there are a lot of them)

Here is a reproducible example that gets the single key-object. **How would I proceed to get more than one hashtags (mentions will be same)? Currently I have to manually specify. Anyways to get them all in one go or something?**
I was able to get csv using this code here:

```py
import json
import csv
import io

# creates a .csv file using a Twitter .json file
# the fields have to be set manually

def extract_json(fileobj):

    # Iterates over an open JSONL file and yields
    # decoded lines.  Closes the file once it has been
    # read completely.

    with fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            yield json.loads(line)

#path to the jsonl file
data_json = io.open('output-2020-01-21.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') # Opens in the JSONL file
data_python = extract_json(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') #opens csv file

#if you're adding additional columns please don't forget to add them here
fields = u'created_at,text,full_text, screen_name,followers,friends,rt,fav' #field names
csv_out.write(fields)
csv_out.write(u'\n')

for line in data_python:

    #because retweet is not common, sometimes jsonl won't have the key, so this is safer
    try:
        retweeted_status_full_text = '"' +line.get('retweeted_status').get('full_text').replace('"','""') + '"'
    except:
        retweeted_status_full_text = 'NA'
    #gets me only one hastags even when there are more than one
    try:
        entities= '"' + line.get('entities').get('hashtags')[0].get('text').replace('"', '""') + '"'
    except:
        entities = 'NA'

    #writes a row and gets the fields from the json object
    #screen_name and followers/friends are found on the second level hence two get methods
    row = [line.get('created_at'),
           '"' + line.get('full_text').replace('"','""') + '"', #creates double quotes
           retweeted_status_full_text,
           line.get('user').get('screen_name'),
           str(line.get('user').get('followers_count')),
           str(line.get('user').get('friends_count')),
           str(line.get('retweet_count')),
           str(line.get('favorite_count'))]



    row_joined = u','.join(row)
    csv_out.write(row_joined)
    csv_out.write(u'\n')

csv_out.close()
```

I did made an attempt but it gave me an error. I can't seem to find a solution in SO either. Little weaker in json at the moment, so would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: what problem you are exactly facing?

Comment: Hi Sahil, I can't get the hastags (and similarly user mentions which are in the 'entities' key). `line.get('entities').get('hashtags')[0].get('text')` gives me error. There are lot of hashtags, was wondering if I can them all in either new column, or get in a string form which i can then put in a single column name "Hastags"

Comment: There are lots of hastags with empty list thats why its resulting into error. Use try and catch. Because you are accessing index from empty list.

Comment: Ssorry I may have miscommunicate with you (not englishspeaker), I can get the single ones yes but, if there more than one hastags, how will I get them without specifying the position `[0]` Can i somehow get them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import csv
import io

def extract_json(fileobj):
    with fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            yield json.loads(line)

data_json = io.open('a.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
data_python = extract_json(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')

fields = u'created_at,text,full_text, screen_name,followers,friends,rt,fav' 
csv_out.write(fields)
csv_out.write(u'\n')

for line in data_python:

    try:
        retweeted_status_full_text = '"' +line.get('retweeted_status').get('full_text').replace('"','""') + '"'
    except:
        retweeted_status_full_text = 'NA'

    try:
      temp = line.get('entities').get('hashtags')
      entities = ""
      for val in temp:
        entities += '"' + val.get('text').replace('"', '""') + '"' + ' '
    except:
      entities = ""

    row = [line.get('created_at'),
           '"' + line.get('full_text').replace('"','""') + '"',
           retweeted_status_full_text,
           line.get('user').get('screen_name'),
           str(line.get('user').get('followers_count')),
           str(line.get('user').get('friends_count')),
           str(line.get('retweet_count')),
           str(line.get('favorite_count'))]

    print('entities' + ' ' + str(entities))

    row_joined = u','.join(row)
    csv_out.write(row_joined)
    csv_out.write(u'\n')

csv_out.close()
```

I tried something like this. I replaced empty entities with entities = ''

Comment: Thank you Sahil, sorry about wrong communication. Like how would I go on about if I need to get all the hastags? This gets me one hastags, what if some has 3 or 6 and so on?

Comment: @AOE_player i have updated the code. Check if it works

Comment: Thank you Sir!! Yes this is wonderful. Have a blessed day bro.

Comment: I see `val` becomes the key afterwards. I didn't thought of using an inner loop